# Cancel instances of dart.async.StreamSubscription

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, stream

When I use "StreamSubscription" to instance a value.

```
  StreamSubscription? _webViewListener;
```

It always show the problem

> Cancel instances of dart.async.StreamSubscription.

I promise that there has dispose function.

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _webViewListener!.cancel();
    _webViewListener = null;
    topController!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

I have seen the [offical methods](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/cancel_subscriptions.html). However, it does not work for me.

At last, I want to know the function of **StreamSubscription**. And how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important feature of StreamSubscription is the ability to dispose it. If you don't do this, even though you don't need the subscription anymore, e.g. after leaving a page in Flutter, the stream or the subscription will run forever until the whole program is closed.
If you dispose all subscriptions in the dispose function of your state, you should be able to ignore this warning. Sometimes such warnings are displayed incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer is of use to me very much. It works for me. I believe that i can earn some valueful experience from it. Thanks again.